# How to eliminate "unnecessary" values to a neural network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

My professor asked my class to make a neural network to try to predict if a breast cancer is benign or malignant. To do this I'm using the [Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29).

As a tip for doing this my professor said not all 30 atributes needs to be used as an input (there are 32, but the first 2 are the ID and Diagnosis), what I want to ask is: How am I supposed to take those 30 inputs (that would create like 100+ weights depending on how many neurons I would use) and get them into a lesser number?

I've already found how to "prune" a neural net, but I don't think that's what I want. I'm not trying to eliminate unnecessary neurons, but to shrink the input itself.

PS: Sorry for any english errors, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a question that is being under research right now. It is called feature selection and there are some techniques already. One is `Principal Componetns Analysis (PCA)` that reduces the dimensionality of your dataset taking those feature that keeps the most variance. Another thing you can do is to see if there are highly corelated variables. If two inputs are highly correlated may mean that they carry almost the same information so it may be remove without worsen much the performance of your classifier. As a third technique you could use is `deep-learning` which is a technique that tries to learn the features that will later be used to feed your trainer. More info about deep learning and PCA can be found here http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

This problem is called [feature selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-selection). It is mostly the same for neural networks as for other classifiers. You could prune your dataset while retaining the most variance using PCA. To go further, you could use a greedy approach and evaluate your features one by one by training and testing your network with each feature excluded in turn.

Comment: I think with 30 attributes it could be a disaster to check them one by one, two by two and so on. You can do a PCA and start training with 1, 2, 3, ... best features and choose what gives you best accuracy in less time.

Answer (score 2):

### There is a technique for `feature selection` using just neural networks

Split your dataset into three groups:

- *Training data* used for supervised training
- *Validation data* used to verify that the neural network is able to generalize
- *Accuracy testing* used to test which of the features are required

#### The steps:

1. Train a network on your training and validation set, just like you would normally do.
2. Test the accuracy of the network with the third dataset.
3. Locate the varible which yields the smallest drop in the accuracy test above when dropped (dropped meaning always feeding a zero as the input signal )
4. Retrain your network with the new selection of features
5. Keep doing this either to the network fails to be trained or there is just one variable left.

[Here is a paper on the technique](http://funk.on.br/esantos/doutorado/INTELIG%CANCIA%20ARTIFICIAL/T%C9CNICAS/REDES%20NEURAIS/ARTIGOS%20RN/29.pdf)